# Elixir: Convert list of bits to binary

Tags: elixir

I have a list of integers representing bits; e.g. `[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]` and I would like to convert it into a binary i.e. `<<153, 28>>`, I know that the length of the list will always be a multiple of 8.

I have looked at the Elixir documentation, but I have not been able to find any help (I have looked for the exact function but also for a function for appending a bit to a binary).

I have written a function which solves the problem (below) but I hoped there was a better way as I think my function looks too complicated.

```
def list_to_binary(l) do 
  if length(l) >= 8 do
    << Enum.at(l, 0) :: size(1),
      Enum.at(l, 1) :: size(1),
      Enum.at(l, 2) :: size(1),
      Enum.at(l, 3) :: size(1),
      Enum.at(l, 4) :: size(1),
      Enum.at(l, 5) :: size(1),
      Enum.at(l, 6) :: size(1),
      Enum.at(l, 7) :: size(1)
    >> <> list_to_binary(Enum.drop l, 8)
  else
    if length(l) == 0 do
      <<>>
    else
      l = l ++ List.duplicate(0, 8 - length(l))
      list_to_binary(l)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension: it’s [`into` keyword argument](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1-into) accepts anything implementing [`Collectable`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Collectable.html) protocol and `binary` indeed does implement it.

```rb
for i <- [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0], do: <<i::1>>, into: <<>>
#⇒ <<153, 28>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @mudasobwa's answer above, you can do

```rb
Enum.into([1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0], <<>>, fn bit -> <<bit :: 1>> end)
```

I think this is slightly cleaner as `Enum.into` can be placed into a pipeline easily.