# Need to convert string of 1s and 0s as a binary representation into a decimal number

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am creating a subnetting program and have been able to convert the octets to a concatenated binary representation, but the problem I am facing is that the representation is in a string format:

```
IO.inspect(binary_subnet_address)
"11000000101010001100100000100000"
```

This is the subnetted address in binary, but how do I change it back into a grouping of 8 bits for each octet and convert it back to a decimal number?

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365157/elixir-convert-list-of-bits-to-binary) but it doesn't specify how to change the binary back into a decimal number, and I am honestly not sure how to turn the string into a list of 8 items as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your string:

> "11000000101010001100100000100000"

contains only ASCII characters, each character is one byte long.  That allows you to use a [bitstring comprehension](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) to extract 8 characters (= 8 bytes) at a time from your string:

```
defmodule A do

  def split(str) do
    for <<chunk::binary-size(8) <- str>> do 
      String.to_integer(chunk, 2)
    end
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(13)> c "a.ex"                                    
warning: redefining module A (current version defined in memory)
  a.ex:1

[A]

iex(14)> A.split "11000000101010001100100000100000"
[192, 168, 200, 32]
```

> have been able to convert the octets to a concatenated binary representation

You should post what you started with and then we can show you how to dispense with all the unnecessary stuff you probably did.

Comment: The full code is kludgy as hell, I've been trying to build this program in different languages for years and Elixir is the first one that got me anywhere close! So I'm drawing with really large crayons here, but any advice would be appreciated. The ultimate goal is to put this up as a Phoenix website to teach subnetting visually, so I need to send back a struct:

https://github.com/roostercrab/subnetter

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you just want to use `String.to_integer/2` with base 2 on each part, right?

```rb
iex> for offset <- 0..3 do
...>   "11000000101010001100100000100000"
...>   |> binary_part(offset * 8, 8)
...>   |> String.to_integer(2)
...> end
[192, 168, 200, 32]
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, I just happened to use 7stud's code so I accepted his answer as it will go into the codebase. But I appreciate how Elixir gives not just one but TWO ways to deal with raw binary! If you are bored and would like to help tighten up the code it is here:

https://github.com/roostercrab/subnetter

Comment: I actually converted it with Integer.to_string, I didn't even think to just reverse the two. Elixir is so logical!

Comment: Yeah, I like his answer better. I don't have that much experience with bitstring comprehensions.

Comment: What does offset do in your code though? I would have thought that we would use 0..7 because we want chunks of eight but your result comes out as though they were 8 bit numbers.

Comment: Ah wait I see, it does it 4 times. Fantastic. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another (faster) option would be to use [`Bitwise`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Bitwise.html) for direct bits access, without a necessity to call `String.to_integer(2)` at all.

```rb
import Bitwise

input = "11000000101010001100100000100000"

for << <<b7, b6, b5, b4, b3, b2, b1, b0>> <- input>>,
  do: ((b7 - ?0) <<< 7) +
      ((b6 - ?0) <<< 6) +
      ((b5 - ?0) <<< 5) +
      ((b4 - ?0) <<< 4) +
      ((b3 - ?0) <<< 3) +
      ((b2 - ?0) <<< 2) +
      ((b1 - ?0) <<< 1) +
      ((b0 - ?0) <<< 0)
#⇒ [192, 168, 200, 32]
```

The above might be made shorter with a macro, but I do not think it’s worth it here.